# Swift(iOS) two scroll view in one view controller

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I want to put to two horizontally moving scroll view in my view controller. And I put them, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
class HomeSceneViewController : UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var HomeSceneScrollView: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet var HomeScenePageControl: UIPageControl!

@IBOutlet var HomeSceneImageView1: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var HomeSceneImageView2: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var HomeSceneScrollView2: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet var HomeSceneImageView3: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var HomeSceneImageView4: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var HomeScenePageControl2: UIPageControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   self.HomeSceneScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.HomeSceneScrollView.frame.height)
    let scrollViewWidth:CGFloat = self.HomeSceneScrollView.frame.width
    let scrollViewHeight:CGFloat = self.HomeSceneScrollView.frame.height

    let imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,scrollViewWidth/2,scrollViewHeight))
    imgOne.image = UIImage(named: "BEST3")
    let imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth/2,0,scrollViewWidth/2,scrollViewHeight))
    imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "BEST4")
    let imgThree = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth,0,scrollViewWidth/2,scrollViewHeight))
    imgThree.image = UIImage(named: "BEST1")
    let imgFour = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth*3/2,0,scrollViewWidth/2,scrollViewHeight))
    imgFour.image = UIImage(named: "BEST2")

    self.HomeSceneScrollView.addSubview(imgOne)
    self.HomeSceneScrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)
    self.HomeSceneScrollView.addSubview(imgThree)
    self.HomeSceneScrollView.addSubview(imgFour)

    self.HomeSceneScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.HomeSceneScrollView.frame.width * 2,self.HomeSceneScrollView.frame.height)
    self.HomeSceneScrollView.delegate = self
    self.HomeScenePageControl.currentPage = 0




    self.HomeSceneScrollView2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 392, self.view.frame.width, self.HomeSceneScrollView2.frame.height)
    let scrollViewWidth2:CGFloat = self.HomeSceneScrollView2.frame.width
    let scrollViewHeight2:CGFloat = self.HomeSceneScrollView2.frame.height

    let imgOne1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0,392,scrollViewWidth2/2,scrollViewHeight2))
    imgOne1.image = UIImage(named: "RECOMMEND1")
    let imgTwo2 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth2/2,392,scrollViewWidth2/2,scrollViewHeight2))
    imgTwo2.image = UIImage(named: "RECOMMEND2")
    let imgThree3 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth2,392,scrollViewWidth2/2,scrollViewHeight2))
    imgThree3.image = UIImage(named: "RECOMMEND3")
    let imgFour4 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth2*3/2,392,scrollViewWidth2/2,scrollViewHeight2))
    imgFour4.image = UIImage(named: "RECOMMEND4")

    self.HomeSceneScrollView2.addSubview(imgOne1)
    self.HomeSceneScrollView2.addSubview(imgTwo2)
    self.HomeSceneScrollView2.addSubview(imgThree3)
    self.HomeSceneScrollView2.addSubview(imgFour4)

    self.HomeSceneScrollView2.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.HomeSceneScrollView2.frame.width * 2,self.HomeSceneScrollView2.frame.height)
    self.HomeSceneScrollView2.delegate = self
    self.HomeScenePageControl2.currentPage = 0
```

I wrote same code with modifying just some details like CGRectMake.
First scroll view works well.(UIImage names "Best1,2,3,4",homescenescrollview) But second one doesn't appear when I build it. Here is the image.[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ik2d.png)

What's the problem? Please help me! cannot find any solutions..

Comment: Why do you have IBOutlets if you are doing everything programatically?

Answer (score 2):

So from the looks of your code, it appears as though you are setting up a lot of things in code unnecessarily. I would suggest either setting things up in StoryBoard ***or*** programmatically, not both.

Also, it a appears as though you are looking for something like a [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/) instead of UIScrollViews. The things you are attempting to achieve can be done with two single-row, horizontally-scrollable CollectionViews.

Some good places to start looking into UICollecitonViews are:

- [This Ray Wenderlich Tutrial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1)
- [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/)
- [This Thorn Tutorial](http://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/want-your-swift-app-to-scroll-in-two-directions-like-netflix-heres-how/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! ZGski.